# SQL Server : select all after specific character

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How I can select

- "ALT1" if value is "W61N03D20V0-WHIH-ALT1"
- "ALT2" if for "W61N03D20V0-WHIH-ALT2"
- "SW" for "W61N03D20V0-WHIH-SW"
- "Default" for "W61N26D1YA1-VICU" (without prefix)
- "Defailt" for "W61N27D21V2-AZTD"

In other words I'm looking for a way extract last part after second suffix, but if I have't second suffix - then default

Thanks for advice

Comment: The logic is not quite clear. can you elaborate?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I think that it should be always the third part of a with minus concatenated string.

Comment: I have added more examples

Comment: Your new examples do all start with `W61N03D20V0-WHIH-`. Is this a rule or coincidence?

Comment: I think you mean suffix instead of prefix. And see my answer below :-)

Comment: just coincidence I can get any string befor suffix, like W6FYK4D25J0-BOGR

Comment: Are you looking for a function or stored proc, or a specific query for the examples you gave above?

Comment: Did you check my answer? It will split a string in parts on its minus signs and deliver the third part.

Comment: Shnugo, I will check it now, thanks =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

First you "split" the string on its minus signs with the XML trick.
Then you read the third node from you XML - voila!

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl(content VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO #tbl VALUES('W61N03D20V0-WHIH-ALT1')
                      ,('W61N03D20V0-WHIH-SW')
                      ,('W61N26D1YA1-VICU');

WITH SplittedAsXml AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(content,'-','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS Content
    FROM #tbl
)
SELECT ISNULL(Content.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)'),'default') AS TheThirdPart
FROM SplittedAsXml;

DROP TABLE #tbl;
```

The result

```
ALT1
SW
default
```

Going this ways would also give you the chance to get the other parts in one go just querying `/x[1]` and `/x[2]` too

Answer (score 1):

I did it using the built-in `substring()` function:

```
declare @str VARCHAR(40) = 'W61N03D20V0-WHIH-ALT1'  -- also works for the other examples
declare @sep VARCHAR(1)  = '-'

declare @middleToEnd VARCHAR(40) = substring(@str, charindex(@sep, @str) + 1, len(@str))

declare @pos INT = charindex(@sep, @middleToEnd)    
declare @lastPart VARCHAR(40) = 
   CASE WHEN @pos = 0
   THEN 'Default'
   ELSE substring(@middleToEnd, @pos + 1, len(@middleToEnd))
   END

select @lastPart
```

Answer (score 1):

For best performance, you can solve it with this one-liner(calculation is one line)

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(STUFF(col,1,NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-',col, CHARINDEX('-',col)+1), 0),''),'Default')
FROM (values
  ('W61N03D20V0-WHIH-ALT1'),('W61N03D20V0-WHIH-ALT2'),
  ('W61N03D20V0-WHIH-SW'),('W61N26D1YA1-VICU'),
  ('W61N27D21V2-AZTD')) x(col)
```

Result:

```
ALT1
ALT2
SW
Default
Default
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking for, the following does what you need:

```
-- fake table
WITH SomeTable AS (
    SELECT 'W61N03D20V0-WHIH-ALT1' AS Field1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'W61N03D20V0-WHIH-SW' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'W61N26D1YA1-VICU'
)

-- select
SELECT 
    CASE CHARINDEX('-WHIH-', Field1)
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Default'
        ELSE SUBSTRING(Field1, CHARINDEX('-WHIH-', Field1) + 6, LEN(Field1) - (CHARINDEX('-WHIH-', Field1) + 5))
    END 
FROM SomeTable
```

Comment: I do not think, that the part before the interesting data is always "-WHIH-"... but this is something the OP should  clearify.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use a `CASE` expression to check whether the string starts with `W61N03D20V0-WHIH`.
If it starts with it use a combination of `RIGHT`, `REVERSE` and `CHARINDEX` functions to get last part from the string, else `Default`.

**Query**

```
select case when [your_column_name] like 'W61N03D20V0-WHIH%' 
        then right([your_column_name], charindex('-', reverse([your_column_name]), 1) -  1)
        else 'Default' end as new_column_name
from your_table_name;
```

**<kbd>[SQl Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c43f0/1)</kbd>**